# Cancel previous http request and run the new one using async

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

My component displays a selected building detail plus a list of building units (apartments) of the building. This is a component html:

```html
    <div *ngIf="$building | async as building">
      ...
      <div *ngIf="$buildingUnits | async as buildingUnits">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is a component controller:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'building-dashboard',
      templateUrl: './building-dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./building-dashboard.component.scss']
    })
    export class BuildingDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
      private buildingId: number;
      private $building: Observable<Building>;
      private $buildingUnits: Observable<BuildingUnit[]>;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.$building = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          tap((params: ParamMap) => {
            this.buildingId = Number(params.get('id'));
          }),
          switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            return this.buildingService.getBuilding(this.buildingId);
          })
        );

        this.$buildingUnits = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            let buildingId = Number(params.get('id'));
            return this.buildingUnitsService.getBuildingUnits(buildingId);
          })
        );
      }

      reloadBuildingUnits() {
        this.$buildingUnits = this.buildingUnitsService.getBuildingUnits(this.buildingId);
      }
    }
```

ID of building is obtained from route parameters. When the ID of building changes I need to reload building details and a list of buildingUnits. There's a method **reloadBuildingUnits()** that can be activated by user by a button click. In such case I need to reload a list of buildingUnits and cancel the previous http request if it hasn't finished yet. I don't know how to do that. May be I should subscribe and then unsubscribe in the controller instead of using async? May be it would be better to use promise instead of observable? I'm new to Angular, I'll be thankful for any advices for improvements. I'm using Angular 7.2.0 and rxjs 6.3.3.

Answer (score -1):

Button click observable emission and router parameter observable emissions are tied with combinelatest operator, so whenever router parameter changes or button click operation performed switchmap will cancel the previous http request and trigger a new http request.

```
export class BuildingDashboardComponent  implements OnInit {

    private buildingId: number;
    private $building: Observable<Building>;
    private $buildingUnits: Observable<BuildingUnit[]>;
    reloadClick$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('initValue');

    constructor(
        private buildingService: ExchangeService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.$building = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
            tap((params: ParamMap) => this.buildingId = Number(params.get('id'))),
            switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.buildingService.getBuilding(this.buildingId))
        );

        this.$buildingUnits = this.route.paramMap.pipe(combineLatest(this.reloadClick$)).pipe(
            switchMap(([params, _]) => this.buildingService.getBuildingUnits(Number(params.get('id'))))
        );

    }

    reloadBuildingUnits() {
        this.reloadClick$.next('reloadClick');
    }
}
```